# Does CMS variable whitelisting apply to EE as well?

Tags: cms, variables

After recent patches and versions it is now mandatory to whitelist new (udefined by an extension) variables. Does this apply to EE version as well, or to CE only?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it applies to both CE and EE.  Much core functionality which is common between CE and EE is identical between the 2 versions so if you get a CE patch it will always apply for EE as well.